# Sqlite3 import without delimiters

Tags: sqlite

I have problem opposite to usual one:
Need to import file into sqlite table and I don't need any delimiters, just one line into one column.
Is it possible to do with command line or I need to write my custom program?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with command line. If it is TEXT data, the trick will be picking a separator that never appears in the text.

Maybe there's no such thing as 100%, but perhaps `.separator "\a"` (bell) or `.separator "\b"` (backspace) would be safe bets. Of course I don't know the data......

Comment: I've tried this, but the trick is that sqlite3 doesn't allow empty delimiter, and doesn't allow delimiter longer than 1 character. I could maybe use some rare UTF8 symbol but i'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko What happens if you try to run the `.import` command on the file  setting the separator to "|" e.g.?

Comment: `.separator "\a"` or `.separator "\b"` (bell and backspace respectively) seem unlikely to be in a text file.